# Android, code optimization

Tags: android, optimization, duplicates

I'm developing an android application and I have a duplication of code. Is there any solution to optimize these lines of code? Thanks

```
Button btn1 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button btn2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
Button btn3 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
Button btn4 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
Button btn5 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
Button btn6 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
Button btn7 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn7);
Button btn8 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn8);
Button btn9 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn9);

btn1.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn2.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn3.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn4.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn5.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn6.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn7.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn8.setOnClickListener(listener);
btn9.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: con you post the layout?

Comment: Consider using Dependency Injection libraries like ButterKnife/RoboGuice to remove redundant usage of findViewById,setOnClickListener etc.,

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Add an `android:onClick="onButtonClick"` listener for each button in the layout xml

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button1"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:onClick="onButtonClick"/>
```

And , add a public method `onButtonClick` in your `Activity` to listen for button onClick. When `onButtonClick` is called depends on the button id, do your other stuff

```
public void onButtonClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    switch (id){
        case R.id.button1:
            // do your stuff;
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // do your stuff
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create your buttons dynamically and add them to the container layout.
Let's say you have a `LinearLayout` as your container. In your `onCreate()` method find the view:

> LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);

Then in a loop you create your buttons and add them to the container:

```
for(int i=0; i<numberOfButtons; i++){
    Button b = new Button(this); //Create the button with the current context
    b.setText("My button "+ String.valueOf(i));
    container.addView(b);
}
```

If you want to use another layout and lay your views as you wish you can use [LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html) and other special parameters like [GRAVITY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) etc.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do here is declaring an array of buttons instead of many variables.

```
Button[] buttons = new Buttons[9];
```

To get them from the layout, I don't see any other solution (except maybe creating the buttons dynamically instead of from XML):

```
Button buttons[0] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
Button buttons[1] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn2);
Button buttons[2] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
Button buttons[3] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn4);
Button buttons[4] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn5);
Button buttons[5] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn6);
Button buttons[6] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn7);
Button buttons[7] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn8);
Button buttons[8] = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn9);
```

For the rest, use your array:

```
for (Button btn : buttons) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Butterknife](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife) view injection library to omit writing such boilerplate code. So your code will look like this:

```
@InjectView(R.id.btn1) Button btn1;
@InjectView(R.id.btn2) Button btn2;
...

@OnClick({R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3}) void onBtnClick(Button view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn1:
            // Do some staff
            break;
        case R.id.btn2:
            // Do some staff
            break;
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the buttons programmatically

```
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Button " + i);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something
            }
        });
        ll.addView(button);
    }

 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not ....

```
void setListeners (OnClickListener listener, int... ids) {
    for (int id : ids) findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(listener);
}
```

and

```
setListeners (listener, R.id.btn1, R.id.btn2, R.id.btn3, R.id.btn4, R.id.btn5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTag and findViewByTag. First, add tag in the view:

```
<LinearLayout ..>

    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:tag="1"
      android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:tag="2"
      android:text="Button 2" />

      ...

</LinearLayout>
```

then use findViewWithTag() to make a list of the button and set the listener:

```
int size = 9;
Button buttons[] = new Button[size];

View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
      switch(view.getTag()) {
        case "1":
          // do something
          break;
        case "2":
          // do something
          break;
        ...
        case "9":
          // do something
          break;
      }
    }

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  buttons[i] = dialog.findViewWithTag(String.valueOf(i + 1));
  buttons[i].setOnClicklistener(listener);
}
```